# Is it easy to factor if we know $k\phi(PQ)$?

Tags: factoring

Suppose we know $k\phi(N)=k\phi(PQ)=k(P-1)(Q-1)$ where in $N=PQ$ we have $P,Q$ being similar sized primes and $k\in\Bbb Z$ is unknown can we factor $N$ in polynomial time?